# What is the first column in R's mtcars dataset?

Tags: r, dataframe, r-rownames

I think I am missing a fundamental concept about R's data frames.

```
head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

The names of the cars here. Is this a column? I don't think so, because I am not able to access them via `mtcars[,1]`. And there is no column name/header for it.

How could I create a data frame like that? How could I use that special column e.g. to describe the data in a plot for example?

Comment: They are row names. `rownames(mtcars)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are row names, to access them use:

```
rownames(mtcars)
```

For column names use colnames, to see both row and column names, we can use:

```
dimnames(mtcars)
```

To modify, for example the first row:

```
rownames(mtcars)[1] <- "myNewName"
```

When data frame is created with data.frame, row names are assigned with 1:n numbers.

```
mydata <- data.frame(x = 1:5)
```

Then we can modify them:

```
rownames(mydata) <- paste0("MyName", 1:5)
```

Or we can add rownames when creating the data.frame:

```
mydata <- data.frame(x = 1:5, row.names = paste0("MyName", 1:5))
```

**Note:**
rownames are not very reliable, for example see [this post](http://www.perfectlyrandom.org/2015/06/16/never-trust-the-row-names-of-a-dataframe-in-R/). (this could be subjective opinion and I avoid them by reassigning rownames to columns)

data.table and dplyr packages *prefer* not to have them. You can always reassign rownames into a columns as:

```
mydata$myNames <- rownames(mydata)
```

Comment: **row names**?! This is out of my Excel-universe! Great! ;)

Comment: btw: Some export librarys (for csv or xlsx files) use the rownames as first column. Can I delete the rownames?

Comment: When I do `mtcars$mpg` the rownames are missing. Can this be fixed?

Comment: to delete rownames you can just do `rownames(mtcars) <- NULL`. Also, when you do `mtcars$mpg`, you are extracting the `mpg` variable as a vector.

Comment: Because by doing above we are dropping data.frame attributes and converting it into a vector, try `mtcars["mpg"]` instead.

Comment: Note that the formal attribute is `row.names` (`names(attributes(mtcars))`). While `rownames` (actually `dimnames`) knows how to handle a "data.frame", there could be cases that will not behave correctly: `structure(list(1, 2), class = "data.frame", names = c("a", "b"), row.names = .set_row_names(1))` VS `structure(list(1, 2), class = "data.frame", names = c("a", "b"), rownames = .set_row_names(1))`

Comment: @alexis_laz feel free to edit or post another answer.

Comment: So, the final solution if you would like to add a new column is col1<-dimnames(mtcars)[[1]]
ver<-as.data.frame(col1)
colnames(ver)[1]<-"col1"
mtcars<-data.frame(mtcars,ver)

Comment: Just thougth this simple argument would do well. ``df <- cbind(new_col_name =rownames(mtcars), data.frame(mtcars, row.names= NULL)).``  Assigning `new_col_name` will replace the default `rn` column name

Answer (score 4):

A shorter one liner argument with `data.table`Package will make the `rowname` a column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mtcars, keep.rownames = TRUE[])
```

`head(mtcars)`

```
      rn           mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Answer (score 3):

This works too using `tibble`.

```
library(tibble)
mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column(var="carnames")
```

Answer (score 0):

- How could you create a data frame like that? =>
  you can *transform a column to a row names* using ***textshape package***. see exemple below

---

***> column to row names***

---

```
library(textshape)

state_dat <- data.frame(state.name, state.area, state.center, state.division)
column_to_rownames(state_dat)
#making 'state.name' to row names in new data 'new_state_dat'
new_state_dat<-column_to_rownames(state_dat, 'state.name')
```

I advise you not to use row.names() to transform column into row names

> How could I use that special column e.g. to describe the data in a
> plot for example?

you can use **superheat package**, for more information, see https://rlbarter.github.io/superheat/index.html , it's more simple and more powerful if you use ***textshape package*** instead ***row.names()*** to transform column into rownames