# Obtain variables used by Random Forest in R

Tags: r

Currently, i created a random forest model in R called:

```
my_rforest
```

I'm trying to access the variables used by the random forest of my dataset, but so far, i did:

```
my_var <- my_rforest$importance
```

which gives me the output:

```
                      MeanDecreaseGini
temperature           6.51
wind                  4.67
heat                  0.3
.
.
.
```

Is there any way i could obtain the variable column, the first column of the output?

I'm currently using the following packages for my random forest.

```
library(randomForest)
library(caret)
```

Comment: Is it the `row.names(my_var)` ?

Comment: Is `my_var` a dataframe? `rownames(my_var)` ?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/38990477/680068

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `row.names` to get the variables

```
library(randomForest)
my_var <- iris.rf$importance[,5, drop = FALSE]
row.names(my_var)
#[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
```

NOTE: Using a reproducible example

#### data

```
set.seed(71)
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris, importance=TRUE,
                     proximity=TRUE)
```

Comment: could you explain what does [,5,drop=FALSE] means in the 2nd line?

Comment: @Maxxx  It is just to align with the example you posted.  If you chekc `iris.rf$importance`, there are other columns as well.  I extracted the 'MeanDecreaseGini' which is the 5th column, and by default the `?Extract` uses `drop = TRUE` to drop the dimensions when there is a single column/row.  So, to prevent that `drop = FALSE` was used